# willDisplayHeaderView being called but text attributes in titleForHeaderInSection remain unchanged

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `tableView` with the `willDisplayHeaderView` below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    let tableViewHeaderFooterview = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
    tableViewHeaderFooterview.textLabel?.font = UIFont.hmFont(13)
    tableViewHeaderFooterview.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.hmDarkGrey()
}
```

I have another `tableViewController` that subclasses from the custom `tableView` with the `titleForHeaderInSection` below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        return "YOUR SUBSCRIPTION"
    } else if section == 1 {
        return "SIGN OUT"
    }

    return nil
}
```

My `willDisplayHeaderView` is called but I am not seeing the changes in the header view titles when I run my app on simulator. I have been searching for answers the past couple hours on here but so far no solution has worked. I thought at first I might be forgetting to set my `delegate/datasource` but that didn't work.

Comment: When you say "a custom table view," are you subclassing UITableViewController? Or are you subclassing UITableView, and adding that table view subclass as a subview of your view controller?

Comment: @jefflovejapan I am subclassing from UITableViewController with customTableViewController. Then I am subclassing from customTableViewController for my profileTableViewController.

Comment: So profileTableViewController subclasses customTableViewController, which subclasses UITableViewController. And your override for `titleForHeaderInSection` is defined in `customTableViewController`, and you don't think that overridden method is being called in `profileTableViewController`. Have you defined `viewForHeaderInSection` in `profileTableViewController`?

Comment: @jefflovejapan sorry I should have been more clear in my post. `titleForHeaderInSection` is located in the `profileTableViewController.` I have not defined `viewForHeaderInSection` anywhere. My understanding was that setting the text attributes in `willDisplayHeaderView` in `customTableViewController` would change the strings in `titleForHeaderInSection` but it does not appear to be working.

Comment: OK, I see what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
  let tableViewHeaderFooterview = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
  tableViewHeaderFooterview.textLabel?.font = UIFont.hmFont(13)
  tableViewHeaderFooterview.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.hmDarkGrey()
}
```

In the function declaration you've got a view called `view` that your function is being called with. In other words, iOS is looking up this function on your class and saying, "I'm about to show *this* view, just so you know." In the first line of your implementation though, you're creating a new view called `tableViewHeaderFooterview` and setting some properties on it. Those changes are not going to be reflected in the `view` that iOS is telling you about.

At this point you have a few choices: 1) muck around with `view`'s subviews looking for labels (messy and bad), 2) try to cast it to `UITableHeaderFooterView` (`if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView { header.textLabel.font = whatever }`), or 3) register your own UIView subclass and configure it how you want ahead of time:

```
class MyHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
  ...
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  tableView.registerClass(MyHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "myHeader")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  if let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "myHeader") as? MyHeader {
    myHeader.label.text = "YOUR SUBSCRIPTION";
    return myHeader
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I ended up trying out your second option and it worked!